# How to set up WireGuard on Ubuntu 20.04 in Docker?

Tags: 20.04, vpn, wireguard

I would like to try WireGuard on my recently upgraded Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS, preferably in Docker, so there are less things on the main filesystem. DigitalOcean droplet if it matters.

Of course there are a lot of blog posts, and the official WireGuard page on how to install the service. What I'm confused about is WireGuard has/needs/uses some components in the kernel to function. I looked it up and those components are available in the v5.6 Linux kernel. My kernel is v5.4.

I understand that the requirement can simply be installed, but to make it a more out-of-the-box experience, should I be updating my kernel to at least v5.6 (no idea how I would do that, but I'll cross that bridge...)? Doing that, would I be losing the LTS-ness of my system? Would I be losing my supported upgrade path in 2 years when Ubuntu 22.xx comes out?

Comment: I would try this wireguard image on default kernel and see if it works: https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxserver/wireguard

Comment: No, do not upgrade your kernel. WireGuard works with no problem (both in server and in client mode) on kernel 5.4 that comes with Ubuntu 20.04.1.